# How to NOT IN condition in a filter transformation?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to filter some specific values out from a table, and I tried using the filter transformation like:

```
ITEM_VALUE NOT IN ('A','B','C')
```

However, I am getting PM Parse Error syntax error. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

NOT IN doesn't work like you mentioned. Please try -
`IIF (ITEM_VALUE ='A' OR ITEM_VALUE ='B' OR ITEM_VALUE ='C', false,true)`
or
`ITEM_VALUE <>'A' AND ITEM_VALUE <> 'B' AND ITEM_VALUE <> 'C'`
or
`NOT IN (ITEM_VALUE,'A','B','C')`

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function,

```
IIF(
(
ITEM_VALUE != 'A' 
OR ITEM_VALUE != 'B' 
OR ITEM_VALUE != 'C') , 'True', 'False'
)
```

Comment: i think the conditions should be AND-ed because final condition is NOT IN.